# SSIS OLE DB conditional "insert"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have no idea whether this can be done or not, but basically, I have the following data flow:
[image: SSIS Import]

1. Extracts the data from an XML file (works fine)
2. Simply splits the records based on an enclosed condition (works fine)
3. Had to add a derived column object due to some character set issues (might be better methods, but it works)

Now "Step 4" is where I'm running into a scenario where I'd only like to insert the values that have a corresponding match in my database, for instance, the XML has about 6000 records, and from those, I have maybe 10 of them that I need to match back against and insert them instead of inserting all 6000 of them and doing the compare after the fact (which I could also do, but was hoping there'd be another method).   I was thinking that I might be able to perform a sql insert command within the OLE DB DESTINATION object where the ID value in the file matches, but that's what I'm not 100% clear on or if it's even possible for that matter.   Should I simply go the temp table route and scrub the data after the fact, or can I do this directly in the destination piece?   Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

Thanks to the last comment from billinkc, I managed to get bit closer, where I can identify the matches and use that result set, but somehow it seems to be running the data flow twice, which is strange.... I took the lookup object out to see whether it was causing it and somehow it seems to be the case, any reason why it would run this entire flow twice with the addition of the lookup?   I should have a total of 8 matches, which I confirmed with the data viewer output, but then it seems to be running it a second time for the same file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you can't use a Lookup transformation to find existing records. Configure it so that it routes non-match records to the no match output and then only connect the match found connector to the "Navigator Staging Manager Funds"

I believe that answers what you've asked but I wonder if you're expressing the right desire? My assumption is the lookup would go against the existing destination and so the lookup returns the id 10 for a row. All of the out of the box destinations in SSIS only perform inserts, so that row that found a match would now get doubled. As you are looking for existing rows, that usually implies you'd want to perform an *update* to an existing row. If that's the case, there is a specially designed transformation, the OLE DB Command. It is the component that allows for updates. There is a performance problem with that component, it issues a single update statement per row flowing through it. For 10 rows, I think it'd be fine. Otherwise, the pattern you'd use is to write all the new rows (inserts) into your destination table and then write all of your changed rows (updates) into a second staging-type table. After the data flow is complete, then use an Execute SQL Task to perform a set based update statement.

There are third party options that handle combined upserts. I know [Pragmatic Works](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Business-Intelligence/TaskFactory/Features.aspx) has an option and there are probably others on the [tasks and components](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/) site.